# Application level use of MySQL single master, single replica

Tags: mysql, tomcat, replication

My production setup is two physical servers running Tomcat 7.0 and two physical servers running MySQL 5.6. The MySQL servers are in a master/replica configuration. It's not a big deal to create two db connection pools -- one for the master and one for the replica -- and choose them selectively at the application level, where appropriate.

I won't pretend this isn't a complicated topic with a lot of subtleties -- let me try to break it down into two basic questions.

1. In the general case, do I want to only write to the master and only read from the replica?
2. Due to replication lag being unpredictable, if I need an *immediate* read after a write, can I can read from the master?

Thanks In Advance
-Hal50000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching, I came back to a solution that's already been implemented in MySQL Connector/J. A rather simple change to `driverClassName` and `url` in the Resource of the context.xml file like:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/my_db"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="db_user"
              password="db_password"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver"
              url="jdbc:mysql:replication://192.168.100.51:3306,192.168.100.52:3306/my_schema"
              maxActive="200"
              maxIdle="100"
              maxWait="20000"
              initialSize="20"
              removeAbandoned="true"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
              logAbandoned="true"
            />
```

works nicely. The order of the url is master/replica/replica/... for however many replicas you have. Then you can set the Connection instance to setReadOnly(true) for reads from one of the replicas or setReadOnly(false) for reads from the the master. Apparently loadbalancing between the replicas is handled by the driver, but I'm not able to confirm due to only one replica.

All described better in the docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-replication-connection.html